# What is the C# equivalent of java.util.regex?

Tags: c#, java, regex

I am converting Java code to C# and need to replace the use of Java's regex. A typical use is

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
//...

String myString = "B12";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z](\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = Pattern.matcher(myString);
String serial = (matcher.matches()) ? matcher.group(1) : null;
```

which should extract a capture group from a matched target string. I'd be grateful for simple examples.

---

**EDIT**: I have now added the C# equivalent of the code as an answer.

**EDIT**: [Here is a tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813053532/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2005/10/10/56498.aspx) on the use of the actual expressions.

**EDIT**: [Here is a useful comparison](https://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=523) of C# and Java (and Perl.)

Comment: @Mehrdad thanks. That's exactly what I wanted although the question got a downvote from somewhere (perhaps a duplicate, although I tried to search SO)

Comment: Don't know. Wasn't me. Dupes usually don't get downvotes. They get closed.

Comment: @Jason: And your point is? That people shouldn't be able to find the answers they need on StackOverflow? That they should try their luck on Google, where they might find the wrong answers? SO was *made* to be the place to find answers to programming questions. Google was not.

Comment: Jason w: lmgtfy links are considered highly offensive and unconstructive here, please don't post any of those anywhere anymore.

Comment: jalf, i agree and removed it, i realize it was not the most constructive thing to do, it just seemed that there wasn't much effort put into the question before it was posted here.

Comment: @Jason w I actually put a reasonable amount of effort into the question. I created Java code to illustrate my problem and asked for the equivalent functionality in C# (which I have posted as an answer). All in all I have spent at least an hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created the C# equivalent of the Java code in the question as:

```
string myString = "B12";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z](\\d+)");
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(myString);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Match match = matches[0]; // only one match in this case
    GroupCollection groupCollection = match.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine("serial " + groupCollection[1].ToString());
}
```

**EDIT** (See @Mehrdad's helpful comments)

The original code was:

```
// ...

MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(myString);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    GroupCollection groupCollection = match.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine("serial " + groupCollection[1].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You should make sure there is actually a match before trying to access `matches[0]`. Otherwise, you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Mehrdad thanks. I had it in a foreach loop which was safe and then tried to simplify it. Have edited

Comment: Yeah, if you are using it in a `foreach`, it's better **not to reference `Count`** beforehand as it'll cause the `Regex` to be evaluated immediately (as opposed to lazy evaluation you get with `foreach`)

Comment: I don't think Matches does any deferred execution. Do you have a source saying otherwise?

Answer (score 14):

[`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) is the .NET Framework equivalent. The MSDN page I linked to contains a simple example.